# json array: How to create new array elements?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

My aim is to get a json array like this one:

```
var args = [{ name: 'test', value: 1 }, { key: 'test2', value: 2}];
```

How can I get the below code to build up an array like the above one?

```
this.dependentProperties = []; //array
function addDependentProperty(depName, depValue) {    
    dependentProperties.push(new Array(depName, depValue));
}
```

By using the push method I end up having a json notation like this one:

```
args:{[["test1",1],["test2",2]]}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
dependentProperties.push({name: depName, value: depValue});
```

Answer (score 8):

```
var args = [{ name: 'test', value: 1 }, { key: 'test2', value: 2}];
```

...this is an array where each element is a associated-array (=hash, =object).

```
dependentProperties.push(new Array(depName, depValue));
```

...you are pushing a (sub-)Array into the parent array.  That's not the same as an associative array.  You now have a heterogeneous array.

```
dependentProperties.push({name: depName, value: depValue});
```

...This is pushing an associated-array into your top-level array.  This is what you want.  Luca is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
newObject = {
 "first": "John",
 "last": "Doe",
 "age": 39,
 "sex": "M",
 "salary": 70000,
 "registered": true,
 "interests": [ "Reading", "Mountain Biking", "Hacking" ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myarray = [];
var myJSON = "";

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    var item = {
        "value": i,
        "label": i
    };

    myarray.push(item);
}

myJSON = JSON.stringify({myarray: myarray});
```

Comment: please learn how-to format code (there's a question mark at the trailing upper corner of the input box :-)