# adjacency list using json object

Tags: javascript, json, data-structures, adjacency-list

I want to create a adjacency list using json object. I would like to implement json object for adjacency list in the following format.

```
var JSONobj= {node1:[{x1,y1},{x3,y3},{x4,y4}], node2:[{x2,y2},{x3,y3}], node3:[]}
```

My doubt is, whether I can add values to coordinate list dynamically such as `JSONobj.node3[0]={x4,y4}`? 
or is there any better way to add values to JSONobj from outside the object declaration?

Comment: Also, just found this other post
  
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067112/json-array-how-to-create-new-array-elements>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push elements into a JSON object since its just a pretty array.

```
JSONobj.push({"newElement":"value"});
```

Comment: but this is not working for me.'push' is working for arrays, but here it is not working..!

Comment: Its how you add elements to a JSON array and a standard array for you you'd probably just want to do this

`JSONobj.node3.push({"newElement":"value"});`

As far as I know that's pretty much it for adding new objects to a JSON array. You could always try

`JSONobj.node3[0][0] = 'x4'` 

But that will give you something like this 

`JSONobj -> node3 -> 0 -> 0 = 'x4'`

Comment: sorry for the late comment!. It is working as you mentioned. Infact I tried another way to implement adjacency list and it is working exactly as I meant. Anyway I got some valuable points from you as well.

Answer (score 0):

[JSON in Javascript](http://www.json.org/js.html) is an ordinary (structured) Javascript object. So, first of all it must adhere to the object syntax. `node1`, `x1`, etc, must be defined variables or explicit constants. `{x1, x2}` is not defined in JS. It must be `attribute: value`, e.g. `{x1: 1, "x2": "a2"}`. As soon as you have a syntactically valid object, you can manipulate it as you like. E.g.

```
var node1 = "node1";
var x1 = "x1";
var y1 = "y1";
var x3 = "x3";
var y3 = "y3";
var JSONobj= {node1: [{x1:1,y1:1}, {x3:2,y3:3}], 
    "node2": [{"x2":1,"y2":2}], "node3": []};
JSONobj.node3[0] = {"x4":4,"y4":4};   
JSONobj.node4 = [];
JSONobj.node4.push({"x5":5, "x6":6});
```

If you want to use this object external to JS (e.g. send it to the server), you need to convert it to a JSON string:

```
var JSONtext = JSON.stringify(JSONobj);
```

If you want to convert JSON string to a JSON-object in JS, you use:

```
var JSONobj = JSON.parse(JSONtext);
```

Comment: Thanks Jiri. Actually there is some problem when I implement adjacency list as I mentioned in my question. I am giving the new solution below which am using now.

Answer (score 0):

I met some problem when I use JSON for implementing adjacency list. First thing was, I cant use a 'integer value' as id in the id:value pair . so I rethink about my problem and approached in another way and I implemented the adjacency list as below(as a list of list).

**Current solution**

The representation of each node of a graph by its cartesian co-ordinates is really a low-level representation. At the algorithm level, we need to associate a single unique number with each vertex; for example, you can map:

- vertex 0 ---> (100, 200)
- vertex 1 ---> (45, 78)
- vertex 2 ---> (198, 213)

I made a list for all vertexes:
eg: `nodes = [[100,200],[45,78],[198,213]]`

in which `nodes[1]` gives the coordinates for vertex 1.

And adjacency list is of the form of a list of list.

```
adj_list = [[1,2,3], [0, 4, 5] ]
```

`adj_list[1]` gives you list of nodes adjacent to node1. and so on..

This means: adjacent to (directly connected to) vertex 0, you have vertices 1, 2, 3.

Adjacent to vertex 1, you have vertices 0, 4, 5 ...

I found this solution is more suitable to my problem. Thanks to Dave and Jiri for their reply.